# How to pull data on to SP Online from an external source without Azure instance?

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-content-type, sql, azure, external-data

I am new to SharePoint Online, so checking is there a way to connect and pull/push data from an external data source like (SQl on prem, Chatter) on to SharePoint Online through BCS or External content types with out an azure environment?

Please suggest.

Thanks